# Securely sharing data with BigQuery/ Hashing

Tags: hash, google-bigquery

I need to share some data I currently have stored in BigQuery, I would like to do this securely, I note from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions) that I can hash values, my question is if I hash a value, how can the recipient read them?

Do I need to send anything along with hashed data in order for it to be "un-hashed", or can I just tell the recipient which method I used to hash it?

Comment: Hashing is not a reversible operation. Maybe you want to use encryption: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions

Comment: Can you save your query output as a Google Sheet and share that with the recipient?  Data on Google Drive is encrypted in transit (sending) and at rest (storage) https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/6056693?hl=en.  This is probably the best in terms of convenience/security tradeoff, but you need to make that decision for yourself or your organization.